# Vue getter in beforeEnter returns undefined after page reloads

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I have login page and then if user logs in, there is user page. But when I reload user page, It shows false in the console even though user didnt logged out. For login I'm setting token in local storage. What should I do differently, why the code doesnt work? Thanks

This is my route

```
  {
    path: '/userpage',
    name: 'User Page',
    beforeEnter: async (to, from, next) => {
        if (await store.getters.isLoggedIn == false) {
            console.log(false)
            next({ name: 'Login' })
        } else {
            console.log(true)
            next()
        }
    },
    component: UserPage,
},
```

Comment: Vuex data is not persistent, when you reload a page all your data will be lost. Try using `localStorage` inside your `beforeEnter` hook.

Comment: Vuex specifically has persist plugin that handles this.

Answer (score 2):

Use localstorage for storing login data so you can preserve it after reload